# RxJS Schedulers

Tags: node.js, express, rxjs

I'm doing some simple experiments with RxJS in a simple NodeJS Express server where I am comparing different approaches to handling and processing requests (based on this post https://snyk.io/blog/nodejs-how-even-quick-async-functions-can-block-the-event-loop-starve-io/). This is the basic setup:

```
const express = require('express')
const crypto = require('crypto')
const { asyncScheduler, asapScheduler, range } = require('rxjs')
const { promisify } = require('util')

const setImmediatePromise = promisify(setImmediate)

const PID = process.pid

function log(msg) {
    console.log(`[${PID}]`, new Date(), msg)
}

const app = express()

function randomString() {
    return crypto.randomBytes(100).toString('hex')
}

app.get('/compute-sync', function computeSync(req, res) {
    log('computing sync!')
    const hash = crypto.createHash('sha256')
    for (let i = 0; i < 1e6; i++) {
        hash.update(randomString())
    }
    res.send(hash.digest('hex') + '\n')
})

app.get('/compute-immediate', function computeImmediate(req, res) {
    log('computing immediate!')

    const hash = crypto.createHash('sha256')

    for (let i = 0; i < 1e6; i++) {
        await setImmediatePromise(hash.update, randomString())
    }

    res.send(hash.digest('hex') + '\n')
})

app.get('/compute-rxjs', async function computeRxjs(req, res) {
    log('computing Rxjs!')

    const hash = crypto.createHash('sha256')

    range(0, 1e6, asapScheduler).subscribe({
        next() {
            hash.update(randomString())
        },
        complete() {
            res.send(hash.digest('hex') + '\n')
        },
    })
})

app.get('/healthcheck', function healthcheck(req, res) {
    log('they check my health')
    res.send('all good!\n')
})

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 1337
let server = app.listen(PORT, () => log('server listening on :' + PORT))
```

It was my understanding that the `asapScheduler` would use setImmediate under the hood, so why does the `/compute-immediate` endpoint **NOT** block the event loop (keeps the server responsive to new requests) but the `/compute-rxjs` does block and leads to server timeouts on the health endpoint?

I have also tried the `asyncScheduler` - this does not block, but it does take perhaps an order of magnitude longer to complete then the `/compute-immediate` endpoint.

I would really like to use RxJS for more complex processing of incoming requests, but feel this issue makes that choice undesirable. Is there something I am missing? Is there a way to get the RxJS solution to work in the same way as the setImmediate solution?

Comment: It doesn't use setImmediate, but [`Promise.then`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/7113ae4b451dd8463fae71b68edab96079d089df/src/internal/util/Immediate.ts#L23-L36). Since it won't go to the next tick until the microtasks queue is empty, I think this is why it blocks.

Comment: Is there a reason `computeRxjs` is async and none of the rest are? I'd avoid mixing promises and observables. They can play nice together, but I've seen enough flabbergasting corner cases to avoid mixing unless necessary (a library requires one o the other).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your responses!

I now have a solution that I based on this gist: https://gist.github.com/neilk/5380684

The `/compute-rxjs` now looks like this:

```
app.get('/compute-rxjs', function computeRxjs(req, res) {
    log('computing Rxjs!')

    const hash = crypto.createHash('sha256')

    new Observable(subscriber => {
        ;(iter = (i = 0, max = 1e6) => {
            if (i === max) return subscriber.complete()

            subscriber.next(i)
            return setImmediate(iter, i + 1, max)
        })()
    }).subscribe({
        next() {
            hash.update(randomString())
        },
        complete() {
            res.send(hash.digest('hex') + '\n')
        },
    })
})
```

It seems to behave exactly as I wanted (recursion - who knew?) - it does not block the event loop, and takes the same amount of time to run as the `/compute-immediate` endpoint, but gives me the flexibility to use the RxJS pipeline capabilities.